# Calling iframe link from other js file not working

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I created an iframe in vex6.html and a js file in styles.gq/test.js and in that file there is the link and id but when I try to call the code in html it does not work.

Here is my code for vex6.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://styles.gq/test.js" ></script>

<iframe id="vex6" width="100%" height="500" style="border:1px solid black;"></iframe>


</body>
</html>
```

here is my js code

```
document.getElementById("vex3").src
    = "https://www.obviousplays.tk/gfiles/vex3";

document.getElementById("vex4").src
    = "https://www.obviousplays.tk/gfiles/vex4";
    
document.getElementById("vex5").src
    = "https://www.obviousplays.tk/gfiles/vex5";
    
document.getElementById("vex6").src
    = "https://www.obviousplays.tk/Gfiles6/vex6";
    
document.getElementById("slope").src
    = "https://www.obviousplays.tk/gfiles/slope";
```

I expected an iframe but instead there seems to be no link for the iframe
it is also spitting out the error cannot set properties of null (setting(src))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the line
`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://styles.gq/test.js</script>` after the iframe tag.

Worked for me.

Comment: Wow thanks so much this was a big help

Answer (score 0):

Error in console: `"script.js:3 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'src')"`

Your script is loaded before the iframe content, meaning that you're trying to initialize the source of an unidentified object.

**Solution**: Place the `<script>` tag below your iframe. It is a good practice to place `<script>` tags at the bottom of the `<body>` tag so we can always access loaded content. However, sometimes it takes the contents a little bit more time until they fully load *(despite placing the `<script>` tag at the bottom of the page)*. I'd suggest wrapping your code in `window.onload = () {}` It will ensure that all contents are loaded before firing the code.

```
<body>

<iframe id="vex3" width="100%" height="500" style="border:1px solid black;"></iframe>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://styles.gq/test.js"></script>

</body>
```

Your code is fine and should work *(pardon for criticizing)*. Anytime you seem to use repetitive code, it means that it can be simplified/automated like so:

```
window.onload = () => {
  // Target all <iframe> tags.
  iframes = document.querySelectorAll('iframe');

  // Loop through list of <iframe> nodes.
  Array.from(iframes).map(iframe => {
    // Update <iframe>'s attribute "src" to the origin URL,
    // and use the iframe's attribute "id" value as the final source.
    iframe.setAttribute('src', `https://www.obviousplays.tk/gfiles/${iframe.id}`)
  });
}
```